# shutdown executor service java

Tags: java, executorservice

If you shutdown an executor service that started a urlconnection, or a bufferedreader, without disconnecting the urlconnection or closing the bufferedreader, what happens, is there a memory loss, and will it slow down cpu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shutting down an Executor does not terminate the already busy threads. Those will run to completion (or orderly shutdown using interrupt). So all resources will be cleaned up properly (unless you missed a finally block somewhere). It is your responsibility to make your runnables handle InterruptedException (and other Exceptions) properly.

Comment: Side note: `shutdown` won't try to interrupt; you can use `shutdownNow` which *will*. Additionally, look into some of the utilities provided via `java.util.concurrent` for more fine-grained control of communicating with tasks.

Comment: there is also a `awaitTermination` method which will block until all threads have terminated. it also lets you set a timeout interval.

Answer (score 1):

Each `URLConnection` class comes with predefined timeout. You can specify time-outs using

```
    connection.setReadTimeout(2000);
    connection.setConnectTimeout(2000);
```

There is no guarantee that this will works as Java doc itself does not provide guarantee.

[URLConnection#setConnectTimeout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setConnectTimeout%28int%29)

[URLConnection#setReadTimeout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setReadTimeout%28int%29)

> Some non-standard implementation of this method ignores the specified timeout. To see the read timeout set, please call getReadTimeout().

**So interruption will not work in this case unless you specify appropriate time-outs.**

[ExecutorService#shutdownNow()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow%28%29) offers a way of immediate shutdown by interrupting threads but since these threads can not be interrupted it provides not additional benefit.

It only provides benefit when thread has defined its interruption policy and it performs interruptible operations.